# STL function for determining if distance is within `n`

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

Let's say I have some container `C` of elements and two iterators `it1` and `it2` (`it1 <= it2` wlog) . If `std::distance(it1, it2) <= n`, I want to perform some action `f`. Furthermore, `it1` and `it2` are changing (possibly randomly) within a loop and I need to check the distance with every iteration.

If `C` is very large and not random-access, calling `std::distance` on every iteration is extremely wasteful, since we only need to determine if the distance is less than some `n`. It's fairly trivial to write some function which would take two iterators and an integer and return whether or not the distance between the two is within the provided integer, however I'm wondering if there is some way to use the STL to accomplish this task.

Essentially, what I am looking for is an STL version of the function below:

```
template <class ForwardIt>
bool is_within(ForwardIt it1, ForwardIt it2, int n) {
  int i = 0;
  while (i++ <= n)
    if (it1++ == it2) return true;
  return false
}
```

Comment: Possibly, but for me there's too much abstraction and too little code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's possible that modern compilers may optimise `std::distance(it1, it2) <= n` to something like your code for non-random-access iterators anyway.

Comment: The function I provided was not meant to be optimal for RAI nor was it meant to assert that it1 <= it2. I mention both of those cases before the function as cases I’m not concerned about. The function provided was simply to provide an example of the functionality I was looking for in an STL function.

Comment: How/why can you assume `it1 <= it2` wlog? `<=` is not defined for non-random access iterators. You may have a situation where for some reason you know that `it1 <= it2`, but you cannot, IMHO, imply that w.l.o.g..

Comment: @Walter I simply mean that [it1, it2) is a valid range.

Comment: @BryceKille Yes, I know what you meant. But how can you know that?

Comment: @Walter I believe he just means in the mathematical sense. He asserts that `it1` comes before `it2`. It doesn't lose generality because if the opposite is true you could just relabel them.

Comment: Based on the context I am using it in. Similarly to std::distance, it’ll just be undefined if it2 is not reachable from it1. I’ll clarify in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's nothing in the standard library to do this automatically. However your solution is on the right track to being what you want anyway. You only need a minor change to make it more efficient for random access iterators.

```cpp
template<typename Iter>
bool is_within(Iter a, Iter b, std::size_t n)
{
    // if we're a random access iterator, use the (faster) std::distance() method
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>)
    {
        return std::distance(a, b) <= n;
    }
    // otherwise go the long way around with short circuiting on n
    else
    {
        for (; n > 0 && a != b; --n, ++a);
        return a == b;
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh yes they should both be post increments for mine to work.

Comment: no need for variable `d`, though. Still no need. you have `n` already.

Comment: @Walter I don't think so: the loop stops after `n` iterations or when `a == b`, whichever comes first.

Comment: @BryceKille Almost. Remember that it's also undefined behavior to increment an end iterator, so in the case of `it1 == it2` the increment (even though it's postfix) still invokes undefined behavior. For a random access it's probably fine, but for a forward iterator it could mean a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Walter Eh, I guess. I tend to avoid modifying parameters like that, but I guess I'm already modifying `a`, so might as well decrement `n` instead.

Comment: If you don't want to modify an argument, make it `const`.

Comment: @Walter No, because if `b=a+10000` and `n=10` then `n` would still hit zero, but it was not within 10 steps of it. There's 2 for loop break conditions.